# Number of complex $z$ such that $|z+1|= |z+i|$ and $|z|=5$?

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

> How many complex numbers $z$ are there such that $|z+1|=|z+i|$ and $|z|=5$?

My attempt :

I got $2$,  that is  $ z=-2, z= +2$ ,  $|z| = {\sqrt{ 2^2+1}}$, $|z| = {\sqrt{(-2^2) +1}}$

Is it true ?

Comment: $$|2| = |2+0i| = \sqrt{2^2 + 0^2} = \sqrt{4} = 2,$$ *n'est-ce pas*?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From $|z+1|= |z+i|$ we get $z$ at equaly distance from $-1$ and $-i$ so $z$ is on perpendicular bisetor for segment between $-1$ and $-i$, that is line $y=x$ so $$z=x+xi$$ for some real $x$. Then $|x|\sqrt{1+1} = 5$ so $x=\pm{5\sqrt{2}\over 2}$

Comment: (+1) for explaining it geometrically

Answer (score 3):

Let $A(-1,0)$ and $B(0,-1)$.

Thus, we need to find a number of intersect points of the  perpendicular bisector of $AB$

with the circle $x^2+y^2=25.$

Now we see that they are indeed two points because $A$ and $B$ are placed inside the circle.